# Best way for one click solution to get latest and publish project with MSBUILD

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, build-automation

I have spent much time scouring the internet and stackoverflow to figure out the simplest and most automated way to build our application to our test environments.  I am using Visual Studio 2012 with TFS 2010.

We do a publish to file system method where we publish to a staging location and simply copy the files to the server.  So I was able to create a batch file which uses xcopy to back up the app, clear the staging folder, build the app to a staging location by invoking msbuild with the publishtofilesystem target according to this post [Local Publish using MSBUILD](http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/59/locally-publishing-a-vs2010-asp.net-web-application-using-msbuild), and then copying it to the server.  This works BEAUTIFULLY.  I even set it so that it asks me which server (we have two QA servers) and what release so that it can fill in those variables.

BUT! (there's always a but) Right now I run this batch file from my local machine after getting latest on the project so I assume it is publishing from my latest local files.  My question is, how can put this on a separate build machine or server (perhaps the one with TFS installed on it) and invoke the same batch file to build the latest version without having to manually get latest on my project.

Or any other input on how to improve this process.

So the ideal idea for me is to allow anyone to launch 1 file and it will build our app as I described without having to manually get latest.  (Right now, the batch file is in TFS with the Project.  Anyone can launch and build but, I'm assuming it will work with their local files so if a developer has changed but not checked in files, it will build their changes and include them when we might now want to...so...a build machine or building from the TFS server would be ideal)

Thanks and apologies for the wordy description.  I hope someone can guide me here.  Thanks!

PS, this is my command in the batch file to build the project including an echo to tell me when it's doing this part. I have switches in the command to silence all output messages in the command window while it's building. (for the % calls I set the paths earlier in the batch file)

```
Echo Building the latest build to the staging location
call %msBuildDir%\msbuild.exe  /clp:NoSummary;NoItemAndPropertyList;ErrorsOnly /verbosity:quiet /nologo  myproj.vbproj "/p:Configuration=Release;PublishDestination=%staging%;AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False" /t:PublishToFileSystem /l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=Manual_MSBuild_Publish_LOG.log
```

Comment: I guess another question I have not been able to find an answer to on the internet is, can I invoke MS build to build off the latest version of everything not requiring any kind of local workspace for it to run from?  I just discovered the settings under workspaces and see that I have access to workspaces on other computers.  So I'm wondering if I can just set up a workspace on our TFS server without installing Visual Studio or not even require a "physical" workspace?  If I had 30 minutes with someone who knew all the ins and outs I know I could figure this out! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do TFS operations from your bat file.  Open a CMD window and navigate to C:\Program Files or Program Files (x86) if you are on a 64 bit machine and then Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE.  Do TFS /? and you will see what you can do.  I won't suggest an exact mechanism because in your question you talk about VSS and TFS.  Not that it matters... but you may want to move everything to TFS just for simplicity.  Anyway, you can set the working folder and get latest in your bat file just before building.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried doing TFS /? from 10.0 and 11.0 but it says "tfs is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."  Also I don't think I mentioned VSS but just Visual Studio.  Our whole source control is TFS but it is 2010 while I am using Visual Studio 2012.  (I think that might make a difference in some cases as there may be a feature in TFS 2012 but not 2010).

Comment: Ok wait I found it.  I just typed tf and pressed enter that seems to have done it!  I see the tf get command there.  Ultimately what I would want to do, is create a batch file (or other method) which anyone could call, and it would connect/login to the build machine, and do all the functions I have described.  So it would go something like this:  Person double clicks file, it asks server and release number, it connects to build machine, where it can build the latest and do all the backup and copy functions I mentioned. One action which does all of the above.

Comment: In your question you stated "Right now, the batch file is in source safe with the Project".  So I took it to mean you had your utilities in source safe and your code in TFS. I have bat files to find all of the changed files in TFS and update the version numbers, but we still RDP to the build box and manually launch the build.

Comment: Ah I see.  Misleading terminology.  I'll update the question.  So on your build box, is it just an install of Visual Studio there?  I'm trying to connect the dots on whether Visual Studio is necessary to build as well as a local workspace or if Running an MSBUILD command can build like from a temp location or something.  I am thinking this because our TFS server does not have Visual Studio installed, only TFS.  Does my question make sense?  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Yes we have Visual Studio on the build box.  We build from one box so that the versions on the redistributable dll's are predictable.  If you build from different boxes it is a crap shoot!  The build box has 'Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Object Model - ENU' and 'Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Power Tools' installed.  Not sure that you need the Power Tools.

Comment: Looks like I can use this getcs command with the -latest operator and I'll have to install Visual Studio on our build machine.  [getcs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413280(v=vs.100).aspx) But then i should be able to call the batch file on that machine from a single batch file on any other machine.  We don't verson our dlls as it's all or nothing.  So I just have to create a file that can connect to the build server and invoke the batch file which will get latest and run everything.  Awesome.  Thanks very much!